# Why is the intersection of Q($\sqrt[n]{a}$) and Q(nth root of unity) Galois? (a>0, n an integer)

Tags: galois-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

With this, I can show the intersection is either Q or Q($\sqrt{a}$).  All I have is that their intersection must be real and all subfields of Q($\sqrt[n]{a}$) are of the form Q($\sqrt[d]{a}$) where d|n.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) / \mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian extension, and so.... (p.s. you might be confusing the issue by considering a specific case rather than an appropriate more general question)

Comment: Oh so all the subgroups are abelian, and by FToGT all of the subfields are Galois?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea I had in mind.